# How to fetch DTMF Tones in Android application

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, dtmf

Is it possible to fetch DTMF tones in android when the person on other side presses 1,2,3.....9 during a conversation? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

See this http://code.google.com/p/dtmf-decoder/.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Its not working perfectly i cuts digits without any pattern. Please provide some solution